# Do all actioncable clients see messages in the same order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

I realize that actioncable doesn't [guarantee messages are seen in sending order](https://manny.codes/implementing-order-with-actioncable-signalling-webrtc/).  But does it at least guarantee that all clients will see messages in the same order?  I'm assuming it does since it goes through Redis pubsub and I understand Redis is single threaded but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Each message that comes from the `pubsub` adapter (e.g. the `ActionCable::SubscriptionAdapter::Redis`) is processed and delivered to all subscribers in a separate thread using the [Server#worker_pool](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fe6b96afd1afaadb67cd70924a698ba99f8cc9e2/actioncable/lib/action_cable/server/base.rb#L80)

Hence, the answer is no. For a particular client, messages are not delivered in the same order they have been published. And the ordering of received messages, for multiple clients subscribed to the same broadcasting, will not be the same either.